# Menu not appearing when more divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have some weird problem with my webpage.

I made a simple website, where there is a background image, covering the webpage, header on it with logo and menu icon... the menu icon and the menu worked, until now... I made two divs, with `height:100vh;` and they are `100vh` from the top of the webpage... it looks great, but the menu is not working.. how, why?

for better understanding.. here is link to the site: http://david.addagio.cz/own/

ok.. so there is the code:

css:

```
html {
background: url(bistro2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

body {margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a{
text-decoration:none;
z-index:10;
}

#header {
background-color: none;
height: 110px;
width: 100%;
top:0px;
position: fixed;
}

h1 {
z-index:10;
color:white;
font-size: 35px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family:Segoe UI Light;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

h2 {
color:white;
font-size: 22px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family:Segoe UI Light;
line-height:50px;
z-index:10;
}





#head{
border-bottom:2px solid white;
margin-bottom:50px;
}



#menu{

margin-bottom:10px;
}

#social_icons{
    height:570px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

#main{
float: left;
}

#main img {
width:60px;
height:27px;
padding:45px;
}

#share{
float: right;
}

#share img {
padding:45px;
width:30px;
height:16px;
padding-top:50px;
}

.menu {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
top:0;
right: -400px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
width: 400px;
z-index:-10;
}

#third {
    background-color:#E8E8E8 ;
}



#second, #third {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
} 

#second {
    background-color:#F0F0F0 ;
    margin-top:100vh;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>UX design</title>
        <link href="styles_m.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head


    <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="head">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
        <a href="#"><h2>O mě</h2></a>
        <a href="#"><h2>Proč si mě vybrat</h2></a>
        <a href="#"><h2>Portfolio</h2></a>
        <a href="#"><h2>Ukázky prací</h2></a>
        <a href="#"><h2>Objednávkový formulář</h2></a>
        </div>

        <div id="head">
        <h1>Sociální sítě</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="social_icons">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

        <div id="header">
        <div id="main">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="my_logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="share">
            <img name="menu" src="my_menu.png">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">


            <div id="second">

            </div> 

            <div id="third">

            </div> 
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">

        </script>
    </body
</html>
```

Comment: You need to put the relevant code in the question (not just a link to your site).  Part of the goal of Stack Overflow is to have a good repository of questions and answers.  Once you've fixed your site, that link will no longer demonstrate the problem and this question will be worthless to future visitors.  If you can't provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), your question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The menu script is working properly. You have to set a top property for the .menu class:

```
.menu{
    ...
    top: 0;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of those added, new divs is now covering up the menu but you have changed the markup as I write this and can't help with the answer. However, this is a typical problem when floated or absolutely positioned elements rise up into a position that covers up another element.

EDIT: In fact, that's the case. `position:fixed` for the header is the same as being absolutely positioned. Then your menu and logo are both floated. These all take those items out of the normal flow which is allowing your new divs to cover them up.